# Parsing Facebook registration form to PHP

Tags: php, facebook

There doesn't seem to be any specific ways to pass it through as PHP. But for:

```
        <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
                 client_id=MYAPPID&
                 redirect_uri=http://www.timerelief.ca/database/register.php?
                 fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
            scrolling="auto"
            frameborder="no"
            style="border:none"
            allowTransparency="true"
            width="100%"
            height="600">
    </iframe>
```

How would I get the variables in the "fields" of the Facebook Registration plug-in form.
I want these to be passed as PHP variables.

Comment: Why not use the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) supplied by Facebook rather than relying on some nasty hack to get an iframe to send data to your server?

Comment: Do you mean, how to get the form values after the user clicks *register*?

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to post value to database and then use PHP explode...

For the javascript get the DOM element iframe and then parse the contents with a loop